# unable to print correct hash key value using xml simple module

Tags: xml, perl

I've been testing use of XML::Simple with perl. I am able to print out some of the data, but cannot print out the file name and byte size in my sample.  Can someone show me how to extract the following information from this xml file?

I would like to get:

- file directory: `/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731`
- file name: `myfilename-00`
- file size: `1234567891`

So far I can get the file directory, but file name is giving me a hash value and getting file size isn't working.

Here is code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = $ARGV [0]; 
for my $xs ($xml) {
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 0);
    my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 1);
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => [ qw (directory file path ) ]);
    print Dumper ($data);
    print "This is the DIRECTORY: $data->{path}\n"; 
    print "This is the FILE:      $data->{file}\n";
    print "This is the FILE SIZE: $data->{size}\n";
}
```

Result:

```
This is the DIRECTORY: /storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731
This is the FILE:      ARRAY(0x8265c38)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string 
This is the FILE SIZE:
```

Dumper:

sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing time="2011-10-04T02:33:44+0000" recursive="no" path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" exclude="" filter=".*" version="0.20.202.1.1101050227">
    <directory path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" modified="2011-10-04T02:32:11+0000" accesstime="1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000" permission="drwx------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
    <file path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731/myfilename-00" modified="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" size="123456789" app="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
    <file path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731/myfilename-01" modified="2011-10-03T04:48:04+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:48:04+0000" size="987654321" app="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
</listing>
```

Comment: Where is the output of the Dumper print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file` record will correspond to eahc `<file...>` tag in your XML. So you effectively need some kind of loop. Remember, `$data` is effectively pointing at your `<listing...>` tag

I have not tested it, but this is the gist of what you want

```
foreach my $file( @{ $data->{file} } )
{
    my( $dir, $fname );
    if( $file->{path} =~ /^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/ )
    {
        $dir = $1;
        $fname = $2;
    }
    else 
    {
        $dir = "";
        $fname = $file->{path};
    }
    print "This is the DIRECTORY: $dir\n"; 
    print "This is the FILE:      $fname\n";
    print "This is the FILE SIZE: $file->{size}\n";
}
```

Edit: I'm a little confused by your output. With `forcearray => 1` I would have expected `$data->{file}` to be an arrayref, not a hashref

Comment: sorry. i copied and pasted from another test. i edited my output. its arrayref.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, and hardly unexpectedly, `$data->{file}` is a reference to a structure containing all the attributes of the file. Try `$data->{file}->{path}` for the filename, and `->{size}` for the size.